# Change a macro that only works if the range starts with an A1 or T1 etc. cell

Tags: vba, range

I have a macro that works but I would like to change the cell range from

```
Set SearchRange = Range("E1:E12") to  
Set SearchRange = Range("A21:A32")
```

I have made the change in the code but it won’t work when I run it and I’m not sure what the issue is. I have an explanation below the code.

```
Sub Part()
    Dim SearchRange As Range, _
        DashPair    As Variant, _
        PairParts   As Variant, _
        SearchVal   As Variant, _
        FoundPos    As Variant, _
        NextCol     As Long

    Set SearchRange = Range("A21:A32")
    For Each DashPair In Range("B17, F17, J17")
        Err.Clear
        NextCol = 1
        If DashPair.Value <> "" Then
            PairParts = Split(DashPair, "-")
            If PairParts(1) = "15" Then
                SearchVal = DashPair.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value

                On Error Resume Next
                 Set FoundPos = SearchRange.Find(SearchVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not FoundPos Is Nothing Then
                    FoundPos = FoundPos.Row
                    ' find first empty column right of E
                    While SearchRange(FoundPos).Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol).Value <> ""
                        NextCol = NextCol + 1
                    Wend

                    PairParts(1) = PairParts(1) + 1
                    PairParts = Join(PairParts, "-")

                    With SearchRange(FoundPos).Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol)
                        .NumberFormat = "@"
                        .Value = "" & PairParts & ""
                    End With

                    DashPair.Resize(ColumnSize:=3).ClearContents
                End If
            End If  '15 found
        End If
    Next DashPair
End Sub
```

Example with expected result.

- Please see my Excel example, the macro searches for a 15 (as a last number 20-15 etc.) in only cells B17, F17 and J17 currently. When it has a positive result it references the cell below it and uses that number to search cells A21:A32 for a match and place the copy and paste in the adjacent cell to the right of it.
- Example: cell B30 has a 20-15, using the cell below, B18 has a 1 in it.  1 is the search number in the range A21:A32. Once found in A21:A32 range place the 20-15 in the adjacent cell to the right (B21) and increase the last number by 1 so it becomes 20-16.
- Does the same with all cells: B17, F17 and J17.
- After the write deletes all contents in cell B17/C17/D17. There are are two examples in my Excel sheet where the same thing needs to happen.

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXi9p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code lies within `SearchRange(FoundPos)`.
This only works in this application if the `SearchRange` range starts at row 1.

By changing the range to `A21:A32`, your FindPos variable will be `21` for the first case.
This results in `SearchRange(FoundPos)` returning the 21th row of your range, namely `A41`.

Lots of ways to fix this, but to make minimal changes in the code, you could try replacing `SearchRange(FoundPos)` with `ActiveSheet.Cells(FoundPos, SearchRange.Column)`.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code to While ActiveSheet.Cells(FoundPos, SearchRange.Column).Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol).Value <> ""

and 

With ActiveSheet.Cells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol)

I’m getting an error 9 – subscript out of range. I’m getting there using VBA but definitely could use some help if you have time.

Comment: I hope you mean `With ActiveSheet.Cells(FoundPos, SearchRange.Column).Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol)`, you need to specify the cell.

Comment: A blond moment, fixed the "With" but now the message is "Wend without While"

Comment: Should be pretty clear where that went wrong though. Can't really help with that without seeing what you did.

Comment: I'm not sure where to specify the cell.

Comment: I should say which specific cell are you referring to?

Comment: I just mean that you can't say `ActiveSheet.Cells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol)` since we need to say what cells, in this case `Cells(FoundPos, SearchRange.Column)`

Comment: So I added the code:  
With ActiveSheet.Cells(FoundPos, SearchRange.Column).Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol).Cells(FoundPos, SearchRange.Column) 
I’m trying to understand so why would it say is "Wend without While"?

Comment: You'd have to update your question with your current code for me to search for the problem. But either you have a `Wend` too many, or a `While` to few. 
But if you take the code from the question, and just change `SearchRange(FoundPos)` in two places with `ActiveSheet.Cells(FoundPos, SearchRange.Column)` it should work fine. Works for me anyway.

Comment: Hi, with your help I solved it. Really appreciate it. Thank-you. Karen